# Textarea resize when field is empty

Tags: javascript

I have problem with this code
I will create a JS addon to resize textarea when textfield is empty,
i think this code is good but not work for me :(

```
  reason = document.getElementById('reason').value !== "";
  causes = document.getElementById('causes').value !== "";
  corrections = document.getElementById('corrections').value !== "";
  comment = document.getElementById('comment').value !== "";

  var disabled = $('form-control').is(':disabled') == true;
    if (disabled && reason){
      $("#reason").attr("rows","5");
    }
  var disabled = $('form-control').is(':disabled') == true;
    if (disabled && causes){
      $("#causes").attr("rows","5");
    }
  var disabled = $('form-control').is(':disabled') == true;
    if (disabled && corrections){
      $("#reason").attr("rows","5");
    }
  var disabled = $('form-control').is(':disabled') == true;
    if (disabled && comment){
      $("#reason").attr("rows","5");
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to send your all code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to not repeat yourself (DRY)

```js
let anyFilled = $("#reason,#causes,#corrections,#comment").filter(function() {
  return this.value != "";
}).length>0;
if ($('form-control').is(':disabled') && anyFilled) {
  $("#reason").attr("rows", "5");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you redeclaring disabled so many times? especially since its the same expression each time? Just declare it once and make sure you brush up on DRY programming

```js
var reason = $('#reason').val() !== "";
var causes = $('#causes').val() !== "";
var corrections = $('#corrections').val() !== "";
var comment = $('#comment').val() !== "";

var disabled = $('form-control').is(':disabled') == true;
if (disabled) {
  if (causes || corrections || comment) {
    $("#reason").attr("rows", "5");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery all the way?